# Fastest method to find overlapping objects in two lists

Tags: python, list, match, unique

I have two lists of custom objects `train` and `test` of sizes 9,904 and 7,223, respectively.
The elements in each of these lists are unique.

I want to find the elements that exist in *both* lists. Currently I'm using the following approach but it's painfully slow:

```
overlap = [e for e in test if e in train]
```

**Is there a faster way to achieve this?**

Comment: Try using [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Construct two sets from the lists and use the `set.intersection` method

Comment: @yatu Wow. That's so much faster, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@yatu suggested using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), because this makes membership tests much faster - with a list the interpreter has to look at each element successively, whereas with a set (or a dict, though that's irrelevant) hashing techniques are used. You could simply replace the lists with their set equivalents (obtained by applying the `set()` constructor to the list, and you should see some speedup.

There are, however, specific methods to determine the intersection and the union of two sets. As long as ordering isn't important*, here's how you might do it:

```
train_set = set(train)  # Use frozenset if no mutation is required
test_set = set(test)
common_elements = train_set & test_set  # or, equivalently
common_elements = train_set.intersection(test_set)
```

* Until Python 3.7 the ordering of elements in a set or dictionary was not guaranteed.

Comment: That's great. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

To complete @Jeff's answer, we can compare the time of computation for the two methods:

```
import numpy as np
import time

test = np.random.randint(1,50000,10000)
train = np.random.randint(1,50000,10000)

start_list = time.time()
overlap = [e for e in test if e in train]
end_list = time.time()
print("with list comprehension: " + str(end_list - start_list))

set_test = set(test)
set_train = set(train)

start_set = time.time()
overlap = set_test.intersection(set_train)
end_set = time.time()
print("with sets: " + str(end_set - start_set))
```

We get the output:

```
with list comprehension: 0.08894968032836914
with sets: 0.0003533363342285156
```

So the method with sets is around 300 times faster.

Comment: This is an actual and informative answer - mine was too brief. Thanks @dallonsi - this is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
set_test = set(e)

set_train = set(train)

overlap = set_test.intersection(set_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy's intersect1d()`:-

```
import random
import numpy as np

train = [random.randint(1,51) for var in  range(1,9000)]  #Your list
test = [random.randint(1,51) for var in  range(1,9000)]   #Your list

train = np.array(train)  #Converting list into numpy's array
test = np.array(test)   

overlap = np.intersect1d(train, test)
print(overlap)
```